# Cable fault in Token ring

Tags: networking

I'm not sure what will happen when we have a cable fault in token ring network!

*[The Internet Encyclopedia, G O](http://books.google.de/books?id=bW2_KaeKuVkC&pg=PA269&dq=if%20a%20cable%20is%20cut,%20the%20token%20ring%20network&hl=en&sa=X&ei=RKlUUZ-jKoLfOZvKgMAP&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=if%20a%20cable%20is%20cut,%20the%20token%20ring%20network&f=false)* :

> If a cable is cut, the token ring network can continue operate because
>   of redundant path.

*Sybex: Network+ Study Guide 4th edition (page 14)* :

> A single cable fault can bring down the entire network.

Any help for clarification is appreciated.

Comment: Wow, please tell me this isn't for a production network.  I mean, use a freaking wifi hotspot or something.  That said, in my experience (a *long* time ago in college) a single cable fault brought down networks.

Comment: If you find a token ring network, rip it out and get rid of it. Good god, we were _replacing_ token ring networks with Ethernet **20 years ago**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with anything, it depends. It depends on how it's designed. You can build a ring with redundant paths (can survive the loss of a single link), or without (won't survive.) Building redundancy into everything is a best practice, but sometimes it is compromised to cut costs, decrease implementation time, etc.

But, this sounds like an academic question, since you're quoting references. Do you actually have a TR network? How is it built?

Comment: It also depends somewhat on the hardware - I had an interesting experience with a particularly *ancient* MAU (so old it was literally mechanical) where daring to do something as simple as powering off a workstation would open the ring. (By "interesting" I of course mean "Good god get this thing out of here and bring in a 10baseT hub, it would be preferable!")

Comment: I'm not running things on a token ring network! that was just for more knowledge!

Comment: OK - just so you know, per the FAQ, "Server Fault is for Information Technology Professionals needing expert answers related to managing computer systems in a professional capacity."